# How to get output of below program

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

```
string[] groupingQuery = { "carrots", "cabbage", "broccoli", "beans", "barley" };
var queryFoodGroups = from item in groupingQuery
                      group item by item[0];

foreach (var item in queryFoodGroups)
    Console.WriteLine(item[0]);
```

Error in this program please suggest get the output

The output should be  how to group results according to a key. This query returns two groups based on the first letter of the word.

Comment: @abatishchev - you have to look at the total number of eligible questions as well - 5 in this case, and the length of time the OP has been a member - 8 days.

Comment: @ChrisF: You're right, I deleted my mention

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] groupingQuery = { "carrots", "cabbage", "broccoli", "beans", "barley" };

var queryFoodGroups = from item in groupingQuery 
                      group item by item[0];

foreach (IGrouping<char, string> i in queryFoodGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i.Key);
    foreach (string item in i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @abatishcev: I don't think you should be editing to change peoples coding style. Especially so since I think the use of `var` in the query here is horrible anyway.

Comment: @fear agreed. The use of var hides the return type which is exactly what the OP was having trouble with.

Comment: @fear @Josh I didn't want to insult anybody with my edit - `var` in this case (from one point) makes the line of code much shorter what makes it's easier to read and understand. From another - you're right! Thanks and sorry